# What's the point to assert boolean methods?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Yesterday I was discussing this with a friend of mine and we didn't come to a conclusion. While testing, in our case with RSpec, boolean methods, I wondered what was the point of using:

```
it 'should process the payment' do
    payment.processed?.should eq(true)
end
```

The step had to check that the payment was processed, so I just went for:

```
it 'should process the payment' do
    payment.processed?
end
```

Now, I may be wrong on this but, steps act somehow like boolean methods that you want them to return true, so I wonder what's the point on checking that "true is true", I mean you already got the true there, right?

So, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps aren't boolean methods that expect to return true. All the action happens within the `should` method - it performs the test and determines the success or failure.

That's why you can have multiple `should`s in one `it` block (although it's usually better not to, if you can avoid it).

For example:

```
it "doesn't use return values" do
  false.should be_true  # the test fails immediately here
  true.should be_true   # this never gets called
end
```

I would also suggest rewriting to use the `be_processed` method as suggested by tokland.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to spec boolean methods ([arbitrary predicates](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html)) is:

```
it 'should process the payment' do
  payment.should be_processed
end
```

Note that your second snippet doesn't call a rspec expectation so it's not testing anything (other that the code is successfully executed). I think you assumed that a `it` block checks its return value, but that's not the case.

Comment: Yep, that's what I assumed, guess there's a lot to learn yet, thanks! :P

Answer (score 2):

```
 it "should process the payment" do
  payment.should be_processed
end
```

When you have a matcher of the form `be_xxx` then (unless there is something more specific setup) rspec will check that `subject.xxx?` is truthy.

If you have no calls to should in your spec then you're not testing anything: if processed? returned false the spec would pass